# Understanding Backbone/Marionette Events and Commands

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

Can someone clarify the correct usage of events and commands with the following signup and login example?

A typical app my need functions to

- display the signup form
- execute the signup
- show a success page

and

- display the login form
- execute login
- handle successful login

How could this be mapped to Backbone/Marionette Events?

How could this be mapped to WreqR commands?

I'm struggeling with the naming of the events:

e.g. `onShowSignUp`:

Isn't this an event that should be triggered AFTER the signup form is displayed? How should the event triggering the `showSignUpForm` or the `showLoginForm` function be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events and commands are designed to decouple modules from each other.

Module A doesn't know explicitly about module B, it only emits an event on `application.vent` for example signup for submitted, then B module listens for this event and redirects the browser to success page.

The same with commands, but more suited for situation where You need some kind of information to proceed, for example after a successful login retrieving the username of who logged in. If You don't want to put the dependency everywhere how to get the user credentials, register a command in module A, and then module B and C can retrieve it decoupled from its concrete implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm familiar with the observer and command patterns. I'm wondering how to do this clean and understandable. In my opinion the event onShowSignup should not trigger the SignupForm to show but rather be fired when the application is finished doing so. Would you say that this is what commands are for? E.g. 'showSignupView' command? Do you think it is a good idea to trigger commands from a Router? In my case this would be necessary to be able to react with multiple controllers on route changes.

Comment: I would put the routing logic in a separate module, and trigger an event when a signup is submitted and the routing module listen for this event. The signup module is not responsible for routing, it only broadcasts with an event that signup is finished.